# Why can't I use square brackets in DrRacket for scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

In such a code

```
(define (lookup key t)
    (let ([result (assoc ket (vector-ref t 0))])
       (and result (cdr result))))
```

I can't use square brackets, the error is an illegal use of square brackets. How can I solve this problem? 
Sorry for such a stupid question.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that "Determine language from source" is selected (in the list at the bottom-left of the window), and add this line at the beginning of your code:

```
#lang racket
```

Comment: Thank you, it works in The Racket Language mode. But why doesn't it work in R5RS?

Comment: @AqShvartz R5RS mode implements the R5RS Scheme standard strictly. And, standard Scheme does not permit using square brackets as an alternative to round brackets. This is by design.

Answer (score 3):

In some R5RS Scheme (and other types of Lisp, like Common Lisp), the square brackets are not used as alternative to parentheses (see for instance [this](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-language) for Scheme, in particular the answer to the question: “Is it legal to use square brackets instead of parentheses?”).

For these languages you could use the normal parentheses:

```
(define (lookup key t)
    (let ((result (assoc ket (vector-ref t 0))))
       (and result (cdr result))))
```

Note that this syntax is allowed also in Racket and all the other languages that accept square brackets.

Comment: That's incorrect: [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-7.html#node_sec_4.3) has made square brackets part of the standard. Even many R5RS and R7RS Schemes accept square brackets and even (shockhorror!) curly braces as aliases for parentheses, as a nonstandard extension.

Comment: @sjamaan Interesting. If I'm reading [page 9 of the R7RS spec](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf) correctly, then R7RS changed this back to the way that this answer describes R5RS as being. However, I can't see that changed listed in the 'Incompatibilities with R6RS' section of the R7RS spec. Despite this, the R6RS spec mentions the change that you discuss in its 'Appendix E.   Language changes' section.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line at the starting of the file: 
`(read-square-bracket-as-paren #t)`

See Racket document for [read-square-bracket-as-paren](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._read-square-bracket-as-paren%29%29)